# Speed-up for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, math, range

I have a project in school, where I have to write a program which is heavily recursive:

```
S = 0
T = 0
P = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679
x = 10000000000000
for i in range(0, x):
    S += 1 / (-1) ** i / (2 * i + 1)
    if i == x-1:
        T = S
```

And X is getting larger by factor 10. A run with x=100000000 already takes 26s and one with x=10000000000 about 3 hours.
Do you have any idea how I could speed this up?

Comment: There's no recursion here.

Comment: Doing anything 10000000000 times is going to take a long time. Even if every iteration takes only 1 microsecond, the full loop will take 10,000 seconds, or almost 3 hours.

Comment: BTW, most of the digits of `P` will be ignored. Floating point has about 17 decimal digits of precision.

Comment: btw you do `if i == x-1:` each time round the loop. I'm sure this line and the following one are entirely redundant.

Comment: And what is `P` for, anyway? You never use it.

Comment: If you look at the successive values of S generated by this function, you'll notice that it oscillates between values that are slightly too large and slightly too small. You'll get a much more accurate result if you calculate one extra term in the series and add half its value to S.

Comment: This is your third question where you've claimed a high degree of recursion where there is no recursion at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you are doing the same calculation over and over again, you can improve your runtime by parallelization with `numba`

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

@jit(nopython=True)
def ex1(start, stop):
    temp = 0
    for i in range(start, stop):
        temp += 1 / (-1) ** i / (2 * i + 1)
    return temp


start = 0
stop = 100000000
block_size = 10000000
temp_sum = 0
loops, remainder = divmod(stop-start, block_size)
for i in range(loops):
    print((i/loops)*100)
    start = i*block_size
    stop = i*block_size + block_size
    # print(start, stop)
    temp_sum += ex1(start, stop)

temp_sum += ex1(loops*block_size, loops*block_size+remainder)

print(temp_sum)
```

This code ran on my PC in about 1s, vs ~30s for your code. This could be improved further by using `CUDA` to run the code on your GPU but this would require more careful memory management.

In addition, as other people have said, do you really need to do that many iterations? What is the use case of this code? Does it need that level of accuracy?

Answer (score 4):

BLUF:

Replace

```
1 / (-1) ** i / (2 * i + 1)
```

with:

```
(1, -1)[i % 2] / (2 * i + 1)
```

UPDATE: Per comment from @PresidentJamesK.Polk, additional performance is possible when you change the loop to operate over `range(0, x, 2)` and with this in the loop:

```
1 / (2 * i + 1) - 1 / (2 * i + 3)
```

This is okay when x is even, but you will need to either avoid or address the case when x is odd.  Beyond this, we can gain some additional optimization by application of a little algebra and use for the inner loop:

```
2 / (3 + i * (8 + 4 * i))
```

I have updated the code and the observed results to include this approach.

One thing that stands out to me is the use of exponentiation in your inner loop... all you're doing is toggling between +/- 1.  You can improve the speed of the loop using an array lookup instead and also removing the initial division.  Here's some code with some time comparisons:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

S = 0
N = 10000000

print("original loop:")
start = timer()
for i in range(N):
    S += 1 / (-1) ** i / (2 * i + 1)
end = timer()
print("\tsum: {}\n\telapsed time: {}\n".format(S, end-start))

S = 0

print("original loop remove initial division:")
start = timer()
for i in range(N):
    S += (-1) ** i / (2 * i + 1)
end = timer()
print("\tsum: {}\n\telapsed time: {}\n".format(S, end-start))

S = 0

print("original loop remove exponentiation:")
start = timer()
for i in range(N):
    S += (1, -1)[i % 2] / (2 * i + 1)
end = timer()
print("\tsum: {}\n\telapsed time: {}\n".format(S, end-start))

S = 0

# Take care that N is an even number or handle the case N is odd
print("original loop double step:")
start = timer()
for i in range(0, N, 2):
    S += 2 / (3 + i * (8 + 4 * i))
end = timer()
print("\tsum: {}\n\telapsed time: {}\n".format(S, end-start))

print("condensed loop:")
start = timer()
S = sum(1/(-1)**i / (2 * i + 1) for i in range(N))
end = timer()
print("\tsum: {}\n\telapsed time: {}\n".format(S, end-start))

print("condensed loop remove initial division:")
start = timer()
S = sum((-1)**i / (2 * i + 1) for i in range(N))
end = timer()
print("\tsum: {}\n\telapsed time: {}\n".format(S, end-start))

print("condensed loop remove exponentiation:")
start = timer()
S = sum((1,-1)[i % 2] / (2 * i + 1) for i in range(N))
end = timer()
print("\tsum: {}\n\telapsed time: {}\n".format(S, end-start))

# Take care that N is an even number or handle the case N is odd
print("condensed loop double step:")
start = timer()
S = sum(2 / (3 + i * (8 + 4 * i)) for i in range(0, N, 2))
end = timer()
print("\tsum: {}\n\telapsed time: {}\n".format(S, end-start))
```

Output:

```
original loop:
    sum: 0.7853981383974479
    elapsed time: 8.1625896

original loop remove initial division:
    sum: 0.7853981383974479
    elapsed time: 7.968116500000001

original loop remove exponentiation:
    sum: 0.7853981383974479
    elapsed time: 2.9961853000000005

original loop double step:
    sum: 0.7853981383972237
    elapsed time: 1.6683908999999986

condensed loop:
    sum: 0.7853981383974479
    elapsed time: 7.5588762

condensed loop remove initial division:
    sum: 0.7853981383974479
    elapsed time: 7.3124993999999965

condensed loop remove exponentiation:
    sum: 0.7853981383974479
    elapsed time: 2.331167800000003

condensed loop double step:
    sum: 0.7853981383972237
    elapsed time: 1.2696155000000005
```

The last few digits are a little off, but that should be expected for for so many floating point operations used to arrive at the sum.

Comment: Do you know why, when replace the `s+=` line in my answer with any of your alternative methods, the code actually runs slower? Is it a quirk with using `@jit`?

Comment: @TomMcLean - Not sure.  If I get a chance I'll look into it.

Comment: Excellent point with the modulo! I'll definitely use that when toggling.

Comment: Or you could just do two iterations each time through the loop,  S += 1/(2*i+1) - 1/(2*i+3), looping over range(0, x, 2) and dispense with the modulo and the lookup entirely.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I took your suggestion and ran with it a bit...

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a lot you could do here because that is a lot of iterations of your loop. If you want your loop to run faster you need to do less in it.

I see no reason for your section

```
if i == x-1:
    T = S
```

because it only runs in the final iteration of your for loop. Delete that part and write it under your loop so it'll run after the loop is finished. You've now saved 10000000000 checks of the value of i.

```
for i in range(0, x):
    S += 1 / (-1) ** i / (2 * i + 1)
T=S
```

Another option is to put all this in a call to `sum()`

```
S = sum(1/(-1)**i / (2 * i + 1) for i in range(x))
T=S
```

Now some side notes.

As has been pointed out in the comments of your question, this isn't recursion. Recursion is when a function calls itself.

Secondly, this looks like you're trying to calculate a final value of some constant. From a software engineering point of view, you'd be best working out with pen and paper what that final value is mathematically arather than brute forcing it with 100 trillion iterations of a loop. If you do need to calculate a value iteratively (sure, there are some times you need to do this) try to figure out how far off a final solution you are and exit your loop when you get pretty close. For example, in the first 100 iterations your value of S will change a lot, but the next 100 will change less, and so on. After 1 million iterations, do any more make any significant difference? You can probably exit your loop early.

Comment: I think he's trying to calculate π.

Comment: Okay, so that's the infinite series for pi? Basically then if the application needs it to 10 digits for acceptable accuracy, keep going until you have 11 or 12 digits not changing any more then stop. If the exercise is to calculate pi as far as you can, then this whole architecture isn't going to work, as you point out in your comment about the precision of floating point.

Comment: It's about calculating the difference between pi and this method, therefore I use as many decimals as possible